# How to make an Ajax request (XMLHttpRequest) for a chrome extension (manifest v3) and retrieve a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, and I'd like to pass a JS variable `var job = "web";` to a php file called scan.php, and attached it to `<p id="demo"></p>` that is included on my HTML test page, this code works fine on my webserver but for some reasons not in my chrome extension. I don't have any error in the chrome console, so I'm not sure what to look for. Maybe something with the permission, maybe the scan.php can't be read, I tried different path with and without chrome-extension://my_chrome_extension_id/file_root_folder.php and scan.php only.

**contentScript.js**

```
(function() {
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "chrome-extension://XXXXXXXX/scan.php", true);
      
      var job = "web";
      
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("job=" + job);
})();
```

**Manifest V3**

```
{
  "name": "Inject MV3",
  "version": "0.01",
  "description": "-",
  "background":{
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**Background.js**

```
try{

  //ON page change
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete'){
    //if (changeInfo.url) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        files: ['contentScript.js'],
        target: {tabId: tab.id}
      });
    //}
    }
  });


}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script src="contentScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML test page where I inject my chrome extension**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   
      <p id="demo"></p>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP file**

```
<?php
  
$job = $_POST['job'];

 echo $job;   
   
?>
```

Comment: Browsers don't have a PHP server so this won't work.

Comment: I believe XMLHttpRequest doesn't for manifest v3. Any replacement for this?

Comment: @FarukhZahoor use `fetch`

Comment: fetch is only for get operation. what we can use for post operation ?